# pip can't find tensorflow-gpu 2.0-alpha

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pypi

I'm trying to install tensorflow-gpu where the version is 2.0.0-alpha0. I've tried these two specific commands:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
pip install -U --pre tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
```

pip says:

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
```

However the tensorflow-gpu page on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/#history) definitely has version 2.0.0-alpha0. I know I can build from source or download the package directly from pypi, but I'd prefer to understand why this is happening.

What am I doing incorrectly?
I've also tried the above commands with pip 18.1 and 19.0.3 to the same end.

I read the pip docs and found the following:

> Starting with v1.4, pip will only install stable versions as specified
>   by pre-releases by default.
>
> The pip install command also supports a –pre flag that enables
>   installation of pre-releases and development releases.
>
> --pre 
>   Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

Comment: Which pip do you use? (`>>which pip`)

Comment: Alpha versions of packages are often not uploaded to the main repositories **pip** draws from.  I'm guessing that this is the problem here. - could it be that you need to do something explicit to gain access to the repository containing this version?

Comment: I'm using 19.0.3 in one env and 18.1 in another. neither seem to change the behavior. I've also updated the question to include another command I tried (it should be trying to get pre versions of the package).

Comment: What's your Python version? It might not support Python 3.7.

Comment: That occurred to me too. I've used Python 3.6 and 3.7.2 in separate environments.

Comment: Make sure you have Python 3.7.X or higher in a 64 bit environment it may work or download it form here https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/2.0.0a0/#files

Comment: @JoeA as stated above, I've tried with python 3.7.2 and 3.6 (which is supported by tensorflow), but that seems to not be the issue.

Comment: My bad and you mentioned below your on MAC OS I might be mis interperting the tensor flow documents but doesn't it say " macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (no GPU support)

"https://www.tensorflow.org/install so it may not work I feel like I would use an Ubuntu VM maybe and try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual version is [`2.0.0a0`](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/2.0.0a0/), not `2.0.0-alpha0`. You want:

```
pip install --pre tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0a0
```

You also need to run this on a compatible Windows or Linux system. The project only [publishes releases](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/#files) for:

- Linux, for Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7, with x86_64 CPU
- Windows, for Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, with amd64 CPU

Comment: I had high hopes for this one as it made perfect sense, but nope. I tried this on different python version too.

Comment: Are you attempting to run this on a compatible Windows or Linux system? See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on mac os.

Comment: Yes, so this is why. You'll need to use the regular `tensorflow` package instead.

Comment: @JoeB Maybe is too late, but in my case the problem was python 3.8