# pip could not find tensorflow 2.0 or 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Silly me to ask such a question (asked here as well [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39265), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521403/pip-cant-find-tensorflow-gpu-2-0-alpha) ). I tried to install TensorFlow 2.0 or 2.1 on a Ubuntu system for mask-rcnn package, but pip could not find the version of TensorFlow that I desperate need. Could you please let me know why pip could not find tf2.0 or tf2.1? Then how to install tf2.0 or tf2.2?

```
albert@GIGABYTE:~$ pip install tensorflow==2.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0
```

Comment: You can see available versions inside the parentheses `(from versions: ...`

Comment: @AliTou [tensorflow 2.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.0/) and [2.1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/) are available…

Comment: @phd but not for their Python version.

Comment: @AliTou Python version is exactly the part the OP missed.

Comment: @phd Sure. I missed `for your Python version` in my first comment. Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tensorflow 2.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.0/) and [tensorflow 2.1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/) require Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.7 but not higher. Your Python seems to be higher version (from the list of tensorflow versions I think you use 3.8). Either downgrade Python or use higher version of tensorflow.

Comment: thank you so much for your great solution